# Deserialize into a specified area

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization

I am looking into the performance overheads with the `bincode::deserialize` (and friends). The deserialized data in question is a large `BTreeMap<String -> Vec<u8>>`. The sizes involved are fairly big (~2MB ), and a is very frequent operation. Profiling indicates a good chunk of time going into heap operations.

I would like to reuse the previously deserialized area for the next operation (I am hoping this would significantly cut the heap overhead, but don't have supporting data yet). `deserialize_in_place` appears to be a candidate, but doesn't look so straight forward to use.

Looking for any ideas or alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "previously deserialized area"? It sounds like you want to reuse memory allocations in some way, but it's rather unclear what you have in mind. A `BTreeMap<String, Vec<u8>>` consists of many individual memory allocations: one for the `BTreeMap` itself, one for each `String` and one for each `Vec<u8>`. It's not a single "area" you could reuse, since the relative sizes of each of these will likely be different for the next `BTreeMap`.

Comment: Are you using the system allocator? If so, I suggest trying [jemalloc](https://crates.io/crates/jemallocator) instead – for some use cases it can be significantly faster.

Comment: What I had in mind was closer to arenas(for protobufs). Basically, all the memory allocations would come from this area, and we keep reusing the arena serially. But thanks for the top on jemalloc, let me explore that more

Comment: Modern memory allocators use elaborate optimisations. In special situations (e.g. all your allocations have the same size) you can get better performance than a general-purpose allocator by rolling your own, but this doesn't seem to be one of these cases. If you can predict the size of the keys and values in the `BTreeMap` you may be able to reduce the number of allocations.